# Grabbing variables from a URL into a MC Query

Tags: php, minecraft

So this is what i have so far, but for some reason it's not working

```
<?PHP
        require MCQuery . '/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( '$_GET['ip'];', $_GET['port'] );

    }
    catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage( );
    }

        if(($Players = $Query->GetPlayers()) !== false) {
            foreach($Players as $Player) {
            echo "<a href='#' class='hint--bottom' data-hint=".$Player." ><img src=https://minotar.net/avatar/".$Player."/50.png Title=".$Player."></a>
                  ";
            }
        } 
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should get an IDE to help you spot simple syntax errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, You have syntax error in your code

```
  $Query->Connect( $_GET['ip'], $_GET['port'] );
```

instead of

```
 $Query->Connect( '$_GET['ip'];', $_GET['port'] );
```

Comment: do you found any errors ? why cant you check your apache error log?

Comment: [19-Apr-2014 22:00:44 Europe/Moscow] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'ip' (T_STRING) in /home/caninecr/public_html/mcquery.php on line 269

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own query to my Minecraft Server. It's working on my server and I have MinecraftQuery.class.php in the same directory so be sure to run it from there.

```
            <?php
                    require __DIR__ . '/MinecraftQuery.class.php';

                    $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

                    try
                    {
                            $Query->Connect( '192.99.0.12', 25565 );
                            foreach ($Query->GetPlayers() as $arrayItem)
                            {
                            echo "<a href='statistics/index.php?page=player&name=" . $arrayItem . "'><img class='tooltip' style='border-radius:5;padding-top:2px'title='" . $arrayItem . "' src='https://minotar.net/avatar/" . $arrayItem ."/40'></a> " ;
                            }
                    }
                    catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
                    {
                            echo $e->getMessage( );
                    }
            ?>
```